# Process with negative quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Today seems to be question day for me, sorry.

The complex process

$$
dX = i\sigma dW
$$

where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and $dW$ is a standard (real-valued) Brownian motion will have a negative variance correct?

Comment: Are you sure i = square root of -1?

Comment: Yes, it's the complex number. I am just trying to see how complex Brownian motions work, and their implications, starting with the basics.

Comment: $X$ is also complex and has a real part and an imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

$i \times \sigma \times W$ is a solution of your equation. Its variance at time $t$ is equal to $\sigma^2 \times t$ which is positive.

Please check this page for more details about how to compute variance for complex random variables:

[Wikipedia: complex random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_variable)

> *The variance is always a nonnegative real number. It is equal to the sum of the variances of the real and imaginary part of the complex
>   random variable*

Comment: Thank you. Yes I think it is almost a matter of definition. The wikipedia page appears to define variance as $\langle Z, \bar{Z} \rangle$, however $\langle Z,Z \rangle$ could give a negative quantity. It does make sense I suppose to define variance as something positive.

Comment: How do you know that the variance will be $\sigma^2 \times t$? what is the formula for variance for the OPs equation?

Comment: The defintion of variance for complex random variable $X$ is: $var(Re(X))+var(Im(X))$ Have a look on wikipedia link for more details!